# need confirmation if the properties version while upgading jdk7 and tomcat 7 to jdk 8 and tomcat10 is correct

Tags: java, java-8, migration, tomcat10

the properties version are: -

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <ehcache-core.version>2.4.2</ehcache-core.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    </properties>
```

I'm mostly not sure about the spring.version and spring-security.version.

Below dependencies are used in the project

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO if you are migrating your application now I would recommend to migrate to the latests versions:

- Java 17 (the current long-term-support version)
- Spring Framework 6.0.8 (https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework)
- Spring Security 6.0.3 (https://spring.io/projects/spring-security)

An upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8 in 2023 just doesn't make sense (except as an intermediate step) because Java 8 is nearing end-of-life which means when you don't migrate to Java 17 now you will be doing that migration in maybe two or three years.

Similar for Spring Framework and Spring Security migrations: all versions below version 5.3.x (Spring Framework) and 5.6.x (Spring Security) are outdated, out of support and probably full of possible security problems that are only waiting to be exploited. But if you start migrating from versions 3.0 to newer, supported versions (5.x currently still runs with Java 8, later versions need Java 17) it just doesn't make sense to not go the last mile too and migrate only to 5.x instead of going to the latest stable versions.

Comment: i know its best to upgrade to jdk 17 but due to some reasons can't upgrade that, i'm upgrading spring framework and security versions as per your suggestion. thanks